# Eloquent returning first row if record request not found in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm creating an application using the Eloquent ORM, and am having a problem while selecting information in the database.

When running the following code:

```
public function index(){
    $user = Profile::select('idUser', 'userUrl', 'firstName')->where('userUrl', '=', $this->User)->orWhere('idUser', '=', $this->User)->first();
    if(!$user){
        echo "user not found";
    }else{
        echo "User found: ". $user['firstName'] . " - " . $user['userUrl'];
    }
}
```

If it exists, it writes the information to the variable correctly, but if it does not exist, it returns the first row recorded in that table.

My table:
[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaGJs.png)

Please, help me to fix that!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `$this->User` and the datatype of `userUrl`?

Comment: Is return result has null value to idUser OR userUrl?

Comment: idUser = int/pk, and userUrl = varchar(30), unique

Comment: The code is good. You have some row on your DB that matches your query even when you believe it shouldn't

Comment: my table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaGJs.png

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good, I used code like that tons of times.

Make sure your database records don't match, maybe it's working as it should but you confused OR

You can do

```
$query = Profile::select('idUser', 'userUrl', 'firstName')->where('userUrl', '=', $this->User)->orWhere('idUser', '=', $this->User)->toSql();
dd($query);
```

To check if the query was made correctly.

Comment: Return:
string(94) "select `idUser`, `userUrl`, `firstName` from `users_basic` where `userUrl` = ? or `idUser` = ?"

Comment: Then the query is correct. The problem must be that you have records matching that query and that's why it returns a valid `$user` instead of `null`

Comment: Is it something on the table?
I updated the main question and put a print of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function index() {
    $user = Profile::select('idUser', 'userUrl', 'firstName')->where('userUrl', '=', $this->User)->orWhere('idUser', '=', $this->User);
    if(!$user = $user->first()){
        echo "user not found";
    }else{
        echo "User found: ". $user->firstName . " - " . $user->userUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Schedy\App\controllers\usuario.php on line 14

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$firstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\Schedy\App\controllers\usuario.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$userUrl in C:\xampp\htdocs\Schedy\App\controllers\usuario.php on line 16
User found: -

Comment: Now my user is found, but I did the tests:
I put my user (rodrigo.almeida): ok
I put my userId (0): ok
I repeated the tests with user caio.cardoso and userId 1: ok
I put a nonexistent userId: not found (ok)
I put a nonexistent user: my user appeared (failed)

Comment: Can you describe more your last test case?

Comment: Ps.: if i put a invalid userId, like 9999, result in "user not found" correctly

Comment: Can you give me the result of `$user = Profile::select('idUser', 'userUrl', 'firstName')->where('userUrl', '=', $this->User)->orWhere('idUser', '=', $this->User)->toSql();`
Of both success and fail.

Comment: string(94) "select `idUser`, `userUrl`, `firstName` from `users_basic` where `userUrl` = ? or `idUser` = ?"
Fatal error:  Call to a member function first() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Schedy\App\controllers\usuario.php on line 15

Comment: You can try to run query direct to you `mysql` with different data.

Comment: Tested with all conditions and works fine... Query:
SELECT * FROM schedy.users_basic WHERE userUrl = 'rodrigo.almeida' OR idUser = 0;
Changing all data, if existis show correctly result, if no exists leave empty result.

Comment: Remove raws from DB where `userUrl` and `idUSer` is null.

Comment: my query (select * from schedy.users_basic): https://justpaste.it/1cr7f and result: https://imgur.com/a/efDg0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it in a way that I did not find exactly the right one.
But it is a palliative that worked perfectly, it follows code:

```
public function index(){
    echo "Página de " . $this->user . "<br/>";
    if(is_numeric($this->user)){
        settype($this->user, 'int');
        echo "Int <br/>";
        $user = Profile::select('idUser', 'userUrl', 'firstName')->where('idUser', '=', $this->user)->first();
    }
    if(is_string($this->user)){
        settype($this->Usuario, 'String');
        echo "String <br/>";
        $user = Profile::select('idUser', 'userUrl', 'firstName')->where('userUrl', '=', $this->user)->first();            
    }

    if($user == null){
        echo "User not found";
    }else{
        echo "Perfil de " . $user->firstName;
    }
}
```